# How to hide under line color of the edittext when it focused

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-edittext

How to hide the underline color of the edit text when it focused. At the same time when it unfocused I want to show underline color in android

Answer (score 0):

Put this selector in a xml. Add your unfocussed drawable id in focused false state's drawable and add this drawable file to your edit text's background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:drawable="your unfocussed drawable id here" />
  </selector>
```